# Realtek 8723AE wi-fi won't connect

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, realtek

I have read a few threads and found driver installs for my wi-fi card, but when I built them I get the following message:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/ian/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can not connect to the internet at all on the linux machine, and am posting this from a separate computer.

EDIT:

```
lspci -v | grep -ia 7 'network'
grep: network: No such file or directory
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723ae
FATAL: Module rtl8723ae not found.
```

~

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0724
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
```

EDIT 3

```
modprobe -l | grep rtl87
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8712/r8712u.ko
```

Comment: You need the `build-essential` and `linux-headers-generic` packages to build the driver.

Can you connect via ethernet?

Comment: No, Is there any way to get those packages onto a USB via a mac?

Comment: You can list the dependency of a deb file with `dpkg-deb -I your_file.deb`. I'm not aware of a recursive dependency check. Anyway... I just realized you will also need a third package. Please see my revised answer and post the dependency errors you got.

Comment: run `sudo dpkg -i --force-all *.deb` in the directory where all the deb files are. Forget Software center.

Comment: could you mark it as solved, so that others don't waste their time trying to solve the issue. I don't know how that's done. I just started using this site

Comment: it's a capital A in the grep command as in `lspci -v | grep -iA 7 'network'`. What do you get when you run `sudo modprobe rtl8723ae` (make sure you spell it correctly). If it works make the permanent changes as I described them in my answer and ignore what follows. If not we'll have to build it again. It seems you ran an update and are now running on the 3.5.0-23 kernel. Since your wifi is lost again you'll probably have to download [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic) and install via Software center by double clicking the deb file and run make again

Answer (score 0):

As I said: `build-essential` and `linux-headers-generic` are required for building

Above the package name at both links I provided below, select your distribution "precise" for 12.04 and "quantal" for 12.10 (by default I linked you to the 12.10 version). In the download section select amd64 if you have a 64bit install and i386 if you have a 32bit install. Choose any mirror you want.

You will download 2 .deb files. Transfer them to your laptop. Double click both these files. Software center should open and let you install them. When both are installed you should be able to build your driver

[build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/devel/build-essential#pdownload)

[linux-headers-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-headers-generic)

EDIT:

You will also need this one

[linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/devel/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic)

---

EDIT2: build error

There's something wrong with the driver code. Open File Manager, navigate to the driver folder for the driver `rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012`. Double click on the file `base.c`. When asked whether to run or display `base.c` choose "display". In gedit go to Edit > Preferences. Toggle "display line numbers". Go to line 320 and change this line

```
IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER |
```

into

```
/* IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER | */
```

save and close the file. Run make again.

If the build is sucessful run:

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723e
```

pray that wifi works

---

EDIT3: make the change permanent

first check if the driver really works

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723e
```

if wifi works after this, make it permanent by running:

```
sudo -i
echo rtl8723e >> /etc/modules
exit
```

make sure the spelling is correct

Now if everything works don't wander off like last time. Because of our work-around you still have static deb files installed that won't get updated automatically. To fix this run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

the ticks in the last command are backticks ` not quotes '

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, but software center tells me they both are missing a dependency, is there any easy way to know how far you should go back to get the dependencies for the dependencies   and etc.?